# Проблема с пустыми абзацами в контентной области у шорткода wordpress

Tags: wordpress, шорткод

Есть типовой сайт на `wordpress` и простой шорткод.

```
function button_promocode_func( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'link' => 'http://google.com',
    'title' => 'Я промокод',
    ), $atts ) );
    $buf= '<div class="sp_button"><div class="sp_button_link">
            <a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >'.$title.'</a></div>';
    return $buf;
}
add_shortcode('button_promocode', 'button_promocode_func');
```

Обнаружил такую проблему: если в контентную область статьи поместить шорткод, который не отделен от текста пустым абзацем, то он выбивается с общего потока.
Т.е. получаем пустой абзац `<p></p>`
затем шорткод, а затем уже контент необрамленный тегами.

Если же есть пустой абзац, то все выводится окей, шорткод сам себе, текст в абзаце сам по себе.

Конкретно эту проблему решил благодаря [статье](http://sww.nz/solution-to-wordpress-adding-br-and-p-tags-around-shortcodes/)

в **functions.php** прописал

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

И все бы хорошо, но если шорткод идет самым первым до текста, то он теперь выводится просто текстом [button_promocode], а уже следующий по списку выводится нормально.

В чем может быть причина и как это решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, вёрстка в шорткоде неправильная. Два открывающих дива, и один закрывающий. Такой шорткод сломает любую вёрстку.

Во-вторых, текст в контенте наверняка имеет абзацы, и вы пытаетесь вставить div внутрь p. Это нельзя сделать по определению. Браузер при этом закрывает абзац, вставляя `</p>`, и открывает его снова после ваших div, вставляя `<p>`. Никакие манипуляции с контентом WP не помогут.

Замените два div в вашем шорткоде на span. Примерно так:

```
function button_promocode_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( [
        'link'  => 'http://google.com',
        'title' => 'Я промокод',
    ], $atts ) );
    $buf = '<span class="sp_button"><span class="sp_button_link">
            <a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" >' . $title . '</a></span></span>';

    return $buf;
}

add_shortcode( 'button_promocode', 'button_promocode_func' );
```

И уберите манипуляции с фильтром 'the_content'.

Comment: спасибо! лишний открывающий `div` сюда случайно записал